# Referencing local variable before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

I have a piece of code

```
for p in activities:
      activity_progress_average =sum([p.activity_progress_compute])
activity_progress_average = activity_progress_average/len(activities)
```

Brings an error

```
UnboundLocalError : local variable 'activity_progress_average' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: If `activities` was empty, the part inside the loop will not get executed hence no such variable `activity_progress_average` will be created.

Comment: Even if `activity_progress_average` is initialized (e.g. as 0), empty `activities` is still troublesome, since the average of the last line is then division by zero.

Comment: you start with `if activities:`

Comment: I did initialize tye variable and it did bring division by zero error but now i understand what is actually wrong with the code snippet ...... ..